# Convert HTML Fragment to csv in powershell

Tags: html, powershell, fragment

I am trying to process the results of a web query. I am doing

`$data = Invoke-WebRequest $uri
$data.RawContent`

which returns this

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=19gbg0sejwxXXXXXXpzwlasaaeer;Path=/informer;Secure
Server: Jetty(8.1.8.v20121106)
<table><tr><td>username</td><td>firstname</td><td>lastname</td><td>idnumber</td><td>auth</td><td>course1</td></tr><tr valign="top"><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">d_smith</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">Daniel</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">smith</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">2221840</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">ldap</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">2017CE1-CTP-8001-101</td></tr><tr valign="top"><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">d_rutherford</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">Daniel</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">rutherford</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">2223039</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">ldap</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">2017CE1-CTP-8001-101</td></tr><tr valign="top"><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">j_smithe21</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">James</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">smithe</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">2221844</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">ldap</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">2017CE1-CTP-8001-101</td></tr><tr valign="top"><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">h_phillipsiii</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">Harvey</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">phillips III</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">2221845</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">ldap</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">2017CE1-CTP-8001-101</td></tr><tr valign="top"><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">h_phillipsiii</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">Harvey</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">phillips III</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">2221845</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">ldap</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">2017CE1-CTP-8001-102</td></tr><tr valign="top"><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">d_rutherford</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">Daniel</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">rutherford</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">2223039</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">ldap</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">2017CE1-CTP-8001-102</td></tr><tr valign="top"><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">j_smithe21</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">James</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">smithe</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">2221844</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">ldap</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">2017CE1-CTP-8001-102</td></tr><tr valign="top"><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">d_smith</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">Daniel</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">smith</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">2221840</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">ldap</td><td style="mso-number-format:'\@';">2017CE1-CTP-8001-102</td></tr><tr valign="top"><td></td></tr></table>`

notice there is no HTML or body tags. As best I can figure, this is why I am not seeing the ParsedHTML option. These are the only properties `$data` has are shown below [image: $data Properties].

$data.Content returns the character codes to make up the text $data.RawContent produces. 
This is the table when it is rendered in a web browser 
[image: rendered table]

How can I convert this table to a CSV or PSCustomObject or something similar so that I can iterate through the lines and filter and process the data?

Comment: You may take a look at [JohnLBevan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361842/johnlbevan)s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31949668/6811411) in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918094/how-to-convert-html-table-to-csv-file-with-same-structure-with-powershell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the response is valid XML, you can use PowerShells XML parsing ability, like this:

```
$data = Invoke-WebRequest $uri
[xml]$x = $data.RawContent

$first = $true
$OldOFS = $OFS
$OFS = '","'

foreach ($tr in $x.table.tr)
{
    if ($first)
    {
        $first = $false
        """$($tr.td)""" | Out-File "out.csv"
    }
    elseif ($tr.td)
    {
        """$($tr.td.'#text')""" | Out-File "out.csv" -Append
    }
}

$OFS = $OldOFS

notepad out.csv
```

The [`$OFS`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/07/15/psmdtagfaq-what-is-ofs/) hack is just quick and dirty to get the arrays converted to something csv-like. You could for example also use the [`-join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join) operator.

The `$tr.td` in the first row produces an array of header strings, the `$tr.td.'#text'` produces the array of values for each remaining, non-empty row.

Hope that helps.

Comment: YAAASSSSSSSSSSS

Comment: When I put in the table, I wasn't 100% correct. there was some additional HTML headers and such before it. https://i.imgur.com/ixc7X7O.png I took the lazy way and removed the content before `<table>` with `[xml]$x = $data.RawContent.Remove(0,$data.RawContent.IndexOf("<table>") -1 )
`

The rest was just like you had, but your answer is 100% correct before the edit