# need to search a html table (msnormaltable)

Tags: html, powershell

We receive a email every day that shows us what has pass or failed its backup.
What I have done is extract the HTMLbody of the email and placed in into its own html file body.html.

The body.html is like the following
11 headings
Server, Client, Status, Group, Job, Size Scanned (TB), Started, Finished, Duration (hour), Retention (week), Expires

Under each heading it has data.
[image]

I want to be able to search the html body.html for the word "failed" (which will be only located under the Status column and return the whole line.

I have tried to grab it into a variable and then do a search on it. But it returns all the code.

Any ideas ?

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$OutlookFolders = $Outlook.Session.Folders.Item(1).Folders

$OutlookInbox = $Outlook.session.GetDefaultFolder(6)

$latestmail=$OutlookInbox.items | select -last 1
$emailhtmlbody=$latestmail.HTMLBody

$emailhtmlbody | out-file d:\delme\test\body.html
```

Comment: If the HTML is small, are you able to provide it for testing? Be sure to sanitise the code first so nothing sensitive is contained.

Comment: The table is big . It has like over 230 lines. I need to work out how to add it to the question

Comment: Yea, don't add that to the question. But you are saying it is a table so that changes how it is approached. Is each row of the table on a new line (in the raw HTML)?

Comment: You need to show us a minimized part of the `$emailhtmlbody`, so we know if it is possible to iteratie line by line or if the contents is compressed (no newlines) format. The image shows only green lines (success), but you are interested in `failed` status. Could be these rows have a different class to search on, but we cannot see that now.

Comment: If `$emailbody` contains valid html, you could examine it either directly or after casting it to `[xml]` This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31949668/6811411) from JohnLBevan to the question [how-to-convert-html-table-to-csv-file-with-same-structure-with-powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918094/how-to-convert-html-table-to-csv-file-with-same-structure-with-powershell) looks promising.

Comment: I had an idea. I think a easy way to do it is to use regex .The query would be to search the $emailhtmlbody for "<tr>......black">failed ....</tr> " And output that to a html file. It will contain all the data and it will already be formatted in html .  Working on the regex search query

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the body line by line, match lines against a regular expression and capture the blocks you're interested in. Here is an example:

```
foreach ($line in $emailhtmlbody) { 
    if ($line -match "<td>(?<Server>.+)</td><td>(?<Client>.+)</td><td>(?<Status>.+)</td>...") {
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            Server = $Match.Server
            Client = $Match.Client
            Status = $Match.Status
        }
    }
}
```

There are certainly some id or class descriptors in the HTML that you can use to only match the lines you're interested in.

I would first build a working regular expression in a tool such as RegexCoach. These can become quite complex.

Comment: Ok I did something a little different      
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$OutlookFolders = $Outlook.Session.Folders.Item(1).Folders
$OutlookInbox = $Outlook.session.GetDefaultFolder(6)
$latestmail=$OutlookInbox.items | select -last 1
$emailhtmlbody=$latestmail.HTMLBody

Comment: #split the $emailhtmlbody data to a new line based on finding <*tr>
$FaildSearch = $emailhtmlbody -split "<.?tr>" | where {$_ -like "*failed*"}   
New-Item D:\delme\test\backupfailed.html -type file
Add-Content D:\delme\test\backupfailed.html "<html><Body>"
Add-Content D:\delme\test\backupfailed.html $FaildSearch
Add-Content D:\delme\test\backupfailed.html "</Body></html>"