# How to delete a column from HTML file via powershell

Tags: html, css, powershell

I am working in a Software Deployment team, and I am working on a script, to automatically display monthly SW updates on a webpage. We have a Software that generates a HTML file consisting of a table with the information regarding the various SW.

The CSS and an excerpt of what the data looks like:

```
<style type="text/css"> .myTable {border-collapse:collapse; } 
        .myTable td { padding:2px;spacing:1px;border:1px solid #000000;} 
        </style>
<table Class="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>ID</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <b>Name</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <b>Vendor</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <b>Severity</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <b>Description</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>15539</td>
        <td>2460049_DEU</td>
        <td>Microsoft</td>
        <td>Service Pack</td>
        <td>Description of Office 2010 SP1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>15558</td>
        <td>2526291_DEU</td>
        <td>Microsoft</td>
        <td>Service Pack</td>
        <td>Description of Office Visio 2007 SP3 and of Office Visio Language Pack 2007 SP3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The data gets posted to SAP JAM and looks like this:

[image: current state]

What I want to do is delete the column ID, and its values so the output will look like this:

[image: desired state]

My post is done with powershell and looks like the following

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -uri $uripath -Infile $htmlfile -Headers @{'Accept' = 'application/json'; 'Authorization'= 'Bearer TOKEN'; 'Content-Type'= 'text/html;type=blog'; 'Slug'= $description}
```

Does anybody know how to delete the column in an easy way via powershell and post the file with CSS to the website?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Hmm.. I have already answered that, but remember you kept commenting new requirements, while all it took was for you to have a look at what is possible with the `Head` parameter of [ConvertTo-Html](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-html)

Comment: @Tomalak, sounds interesting, how would I do this in this case? Am not very familiar with CSS

Comment: @Theo, thank you, didn't manage to get it done previously, but will try again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Convert HTML table to CSV file with same structure with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918094/how-to-convert-html-table-to-csv-file-with-same-structure-with-powershell)

Comment: How are you getting the HTML? Also invoke-webrequest?

Comment: If you can add this css somehow `    .myTable > td:first-child {
        display:none; 
    }`

Comment: @shadow2020, perfect, thank you a lot, will try to add this with powershell!

Comment: @shadow2020, weird, when I manually add the line to the file, it does not work, on codepen it worked just right

Comment: Has be be in the head or inline styling. Perhaps you have an older file cached?

Comment: @shadow2020, sorry for the late reply. So, I edited the HTML file, and when I open the html file with a browser it works just right, not showing the ID column. But when I post this exact file with my Invoke-WebRequest, it shows the complete table including the ID column, as if it just ignored this part. Then I changed the CSS parameters, just to see that SAP Jam ignores the whole CSS and just posts the html content

Comment: Does it ignore inline styling?

Comment: What to you mean with inline styling? Inline styling like <b>ID</b> works, is that what you mean?